# How to fix `kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)` error

Tags: go, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I am developing an application which reads a message off of an sqs queue, does some stuff with that data, and takes the result and publishes to a kafka topic. In order to test locally, I'd like to set up a kafka image in my docker build. I am currently able to spin up aws-cli, localstack, and my app's containers locally using docker-compose. Separately, I am able to spin up kafka and zookeper without a problem as well. I am unable to get my application to communicate with kafka.

I've tried using two separate compose files, and also fiddled with the networks. Finally, I've referenced: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      # Localstack endpoints for various API. Format is localhost:container
      - '4563-4584:4563-4584'
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns:4575,sqs:4576
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      # store data locally in 'localstack' folder
      - './localstack:/tmp/localstack'
    networks:
      - my_network

  aws:
    image: mesosphere/aws-cli
    container_name: aws-cli
    # copy local JSON_DATA folder contents into aws-cli container's app folder
    #volumes:
    #  - ./JSON_DATA:/app
    env_file: .env
    # bash entrypoint needed for multiple commands
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: >
      " sleep 10;
        aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4576 sqs create-queue --queue-name input_queue;
        aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4575 sns create-topic --name input_topic;
        aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4575 sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:example_topic --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint http://localhost:4576/queue/input_queue; "
    networks:
      - my_network
    depends_on:
      - localstack

  my_app:
    build: .
    image: my_app
    container_name: my_app
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    networks:
      - my_network
    depends_on:
      - localstack
      - aws

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    networks:
      - my_network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      # For more details see See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "output_topic:2:2"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
```

I would hope to see no errors as a result of publishing to this topic. Instead, I'm getting:

```
kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made the broker only resolvable within the Kafka container itself (or from your host to the container) by setting the listeners only to localhost.

If you want *another Docker service* to be able to reach that container, you'll have to add `<some protocol>://kafka:<some port>` to the **advertised** listeners, and make the `listeners` as not localhost

Where the protocol is also added to `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP`

FWIW, That blog should cover all those bases.